# Mobile - overflow-y: hidden does not stop the body element from scrolling

Tags: javascript, ios, scroll, overflow, document-body

This is a common issue I have found on Mobile. I have been unable to find a solid answer yet.

I won't accept the following as they don't work completely (**tested**):

**Adding the following to the body and html tags**

*This does work but causes the page to jump to the top. You can break it in Safari if you turn landscape and get the browser toolbar to show on scroll*

```
.noScroll { 
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

**Adding the following to the body tag**

*This does work but causes the page to jump to the top.*

```
.noScroll { 
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    position: fixed;
}
```

**A combination of JS and CSS**

*You can break it in Safari if you turn landscape and get the browser toolbar to show on scroll. This method solves the jump issue*

```
.noScroll { 
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    position: fixed;
}

var body = document.body,
    lastTop = 0,
    startScroll,
    stopScroll;

startScroll = function () {
    body.style.top = '';
    body.scrollTop = lastTop; 
};

stopScroll = function () {
    lastTop = document.body.scrollTop;
    body.className = 'noScroll';
    body.style.top = '-' + lastTop.toString() + 'px';
}
```

I have tried other methods but they don't work either. You can disable touchmove on the body tag but it does not allow you to scroll anywhere e.g.

```
document.body.addEventListener('touchmove', function () { return false; });
```

Is there anything I can do.

A JS scrollbar is the only proper fix at the moment.

Cheers

Comment: "Common issue"? How common is it to have a webpage that you don't want to ever scroll? I'm curious as to what it is you're building, as there may be a better way to approach it.

Comment: It is for dialog box functionality. It scrolls the dialog box and body container. Adding overflow-y: hidden to the body tag does not work on Mobile. This is the common issue I am speaking about.

Comment: Easiest way to solve that is to make the modal overlay `position:fixed` (and let its contents scroll).

Comment: Any examples? The modal is already fixed.